# urllib alternative for iPhone

Tags: iphone, background, html-parsing

I am trying to create an iPhone application which in some point connects to the internet, fills an on-line form, fetches the resulting website, parses it and returns a string to the user. I want all this process to happen in the background. I know how to do this kind of things with python and urllib but in objc I can't find an alternative, from on-line search I found either sites that explain how to use webkit to retrieve webpages (I suppose this is for displaying them to the user) or how to parse an existing HTML file or string. Since I want the file to be retrieved from the internet and the whole process should be running in the background, neither of these solutions covers my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSURLConnection and implement the delegates. You could also use ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: I just came back to answer my own question. I used NSSURL initWithString: to create the url and then NSString initWithContentsOfURL: to fetch the website's data. I saw the class reference for NSURLConnection and I maybe use it in the future. thanks for your quick response.